# BATCH: Correctly interpret environment variables passed by user through set /p

Tags: command-line, batch, environment-variables, prompt

I want to support variable comprehension from user input in my script.

```
>set target=%programdata%
>echo %target%
```

Gives me:

```
C:\ProgramData
```

All well and good, however...

```
>set /p target=
>%programdata%
>echo %target%
```

Gives me:

```
%programdata%
```

Answer (score 1):

After enough hours of keyboard smashing, I've found a solution that works for me, using `call` to re-evaluate the input:

```
>set /p target=
>%programdata%
>call set "target=%target%"
>echo %target%
```

Provides me with the desired result:

```
C:\ProgramData
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue a command line in a batch script, you could use the
escape character at the end of the line, like this :

```
set /p target=^
%programdata%
echo %target%
```

To explain the difference between this formulation and mine :

My formulation makes the second line the continuation of the first
one, so that both are handled by the DOS interpreter for batch,
which also does the expansion of the variables.

Your formulation lets `set /p` read the data and store it into
the variable. This doesn't pass through the DOS interpreter,
so there is no expansion of the variable, so the value stays
as it was read.

What the method in your answer does is to force the entered
string to be passed through the DOS interpreter, so the
variable is expanded,

Comment: I think the /p needs to come off, right? Otherwise you'll just set the prompt text to `%programdata%`. Doing `set target=^` prompts user with `More?` which is not desirable in my case, but ultimately just as functional!

Comment: I added explanation.